# Manually set list order in swift? (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to iOS development and now I'm trying to achieve this effect:

[image: preview]

As you can see, when dragging, the cell's background is *transparent* and items above or below it will move away *with a fluent animation*.

**Either UIKit or SwiftUI will do. Any advice will be appreciated. :)**

---

Comment: UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: @aheze Both will do. Right now I'm just focusing on implementing it. :)

Comment: Hmm well for SwiftUI it's pretty easy, check this out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-move-rows-in-a-list

Comment: @aheze Thanks a lot! I'll check it out now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achievable with the help of table delegates.Just implement below methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .none
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let itemToReorder = yourList[sourceIndexPath.row]
        yourList.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        yourList.insert(itemToReorder, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
```

Don't forget to enable disable editing mode when needed or not.
Use this for enabling and disabling

```
tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the save! This is perfect for a newbie like me! :) And for anyone pursuing transparent background, just set ```cell.backgroundColor = .clear```, and everything is done!